# Spring Integration CachingSessionFactory how to set auto disconnect FTP connection when exceeds IDLE time

Tags: spring-integration

In Spring Integration, if caching session factory be used for FTP, how to set the auto disconnect connection if exceeds certain IDLE time?

Background information:
My program is based on FtpOutboundGatewaySample-context.xml SI sample, I used the "ls" command in FTP Outbound gateway --> split the result --> and call "get" commandy with Ftp Outbound Gateway for each file to be downloaded.

Without CachingSessionFactory, the FTP connection will be disconnected for every file be downloaded.

I tried to add the CachingSessionFactory with an appropriate waiting timeout value. Now, the connection will be reused and won't call disconnect for every file be downloaded.

But now, I don't know how to make the FTP connection be disconnected automatically if no more file is available for download. I guess some IDLE timeout could be set somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the server will close the session after a timeout (configured on the server); the cache will detect the closed session the next time it's used and discard it.

There's no way to set a timeout on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer